# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a navbar using bootstrap on my website. I am trying to have a dropdown box, but when I click the dropdown it does nothing. I believe earlier I had this problem or something like it and it required me to use javascript but I have not tried anything like that yet.

Here is my code:

```
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Options <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <!--                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Options <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                    </ul>-->
                    </li>
```

Comment: Have you included Bootstrap javascript into the page ?

Comment: Yes I have. The link is in my head though, and also thank you for the quick responce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Options <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="container">
        ...
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I don't know what happened, but I just changed my links and it worked! Thanks again!

Comment: To help with issues like that I made a base template for all bootstrap code, where I just have to paste the code I want to test under the div class=row

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `bootstrap.min.js` after your `jquery.min.js` file in your code. If you do not load the javascript files all the effects in your script will not be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I have the files linked, here is the code i have in the head:

```
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I up voted so you can edit your questions in the future

Comment: why do you have two jquery.min,js, two bootstrap.min.css